# How can i use Glimpse in dotnet core3? When navigation https://localhost:44398/Glimpse.axd 404 error happens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, glimpse

I want to use glimpse for dotnet core 3 web application for the following project. I have installed glimpse but when following https://localhost:44398/Glimpse.axd 404 error happens. How can I use glimpse  in my project and active and turn on

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-NewsWebApp-D3782A5E-F34E-48AF-BACC-CAC0B27F8E27</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210221145941_Initial.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210221145941_Initial.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210228144402_AllowHtmlPostTinyMCE.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210228144402_AllowHtmlPostTinyMCE.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210228144629_ApplyHtmlConstraintPost.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210228144629_ApplyHtmlConstraintPost.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210228145236_ApplyHtmlConstraintPost.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210228145236_ApplyHtmlConstraintPost.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210228145424_ApplyAnotation.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\20210228145424_ApplyAnotation.Designer.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Glimpse" Version="1.8.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Glimpse.AspNet" Version="1.9.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Glimpse.EF6" Version="1.6.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Glimpse.Mvc5" Version="1.5.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>


    <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\font-awesome\css\all.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\font-awesome\css\all.min.css" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: `.axd` modules are part of ASP.NET and registered in web.config. ASP.NET Core doesn't work this way, so you won't be able to to use it to monitor an ASP.NET Core application. All it's GitHub repositories are archived, so looks like it's no longer supported at all.

Comment: @MartinCostello what can i use in the core application

Comment: I don't know, it depends on your requirements. Stack Overflow isn't for soliciting recommendations for services to use. I'm just telling you that the answer to your question "How can I use Glimpse with ASP.NET Core?" is "You can't".

Comment: not solution ? Glimpse dead proojec for net framework ?